# Why `synchronized` was made illegal for variables?

Tags: java, variables, synchronized

It is a very easy question but I cant get the idea behind it:

> Why `synchronized` cannot be assigned to Java variables?

It can be assigned to methods and blocks, only.
I personally think this would be a very neat addition to the Java programming language.

Comment: What would you want it to actually _do_ when set on a variable?

Comment: You're supposed to wrap access to your fields into (possibly synchronized) getters and setters, right? ;-)

Comment: wjat exactly do you expect to achieve via `synchronized`, and `synchronized` does require an object (monitor)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Easy automatic atomic access. :)

Comment: @Michael, define `atomic`, b/c I suspect you don't actually mean `atomic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synchronized block protects the complete code block. A synchronized on a method protects the complete code of the method. In both cases synchronized refers to an object it uses as the monitor - either `this` (or the current class object) or the specified object.

First: The requirement for a monitor *object* means that a synchronized field could not be a primitive type.

Second: What should a synchronized on a field do?

There are two possible answers:

- protect access to the reference itself XOR
- protect access to the object behind the reference.

Option one would be a hen-egg problem: In order to protect the access the field must be first accessed. Try to do this atomically on a multiprocessor might be fun. Furthermore: If the access is a write (i.e. the object changes) then the monitor would be on the first object while the second one is installed ... madness is on this road.

Option two: See this piece of code:

```
public class Foo {
     public synchronized StringBuilder sb = ...;
     public void doSomething1(){
         StringBuilder sb = this.sb;
         sb.append("foo");
     }

     public void doSomething2(){
         this.sb.append("foo");
     }
}
```

Since only the access would be protected, both methods do the same. The first version just makes it a little clearer, that the `append` call itself is not protected.

Oh, I forgot: In both cases you could use only the mutual exclusion of synchronized - the `wait` or `notify` stuff would be unavailable - because you cannot attach any piece of code to the variable.

What is left:

Perhaps just a shortcut for `AtomicReference`?

This is such a rare usecase, that changing the language itself is not a good option.

Comment: I guess another option would be that if `sb` is `synchronized`, then any method that uses it is implicitly synchronized on `sb` for the whole method block. So in your example, `doSomething2()` would be equivalent to `doSomething2(){ synchronized(sb){ this.sb.append("foo"); } }`. File that idea under "really, really easy ways to achieve deadlock."

Comment: @yshavit: A note to your idea: Since `sb` is public, this means, that accessing `sb` from another class would require additional code in that other class. Now imagine that our `sb` class changes: It adds or removes the `synchronize` but the second class is not recompiled... Another blow against encapsulation.

Comment: True, but you could say that the `synchronized`-wrapping only happens within the class that declares the member. That would allow other classes to break your atomicity, but that's what you get for giving out a reference that you need synchronized access to. Same would happen if you had `public StringBuidler sb; private final Object lock = new Object();` with the invariant that `sb` is always accessed in a `synchronized(lock)`. Btw, another possible (but not very helpful) option would be to have `synchronized sb` mean any method (in the class) that uses `sb` is synchronized on `this`.

Comment: To be clear, btw, I'm not arguing in favor of these options. But it's the end of the day and I'm waiting for the bus. :)

Comment: @yshavit: I understand that, I did not want to be rude or something like that. Your thought is valid. I just wanted to explore some implications. Hope you get the bus :-)

Answer (score 1):

they have the [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) keyword for that.

Comment: but doesn't involve monitor, though

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't help you. You use synchronized to make a block of code atomic. So most of the time, you have more than one line of code you want to synchronize.

Comment: Very often, you just want to make the access to one variable atomic, I think.

Comment: @Michael: there is AtomicReference or `volatile` keyword for that.

Comment: @Michael, unless `long/double` on 32bit, all variables are atomic per se

Comment: Yes, you want to do work on one variable - but with more than one line of code. So you have to synchronize the whole block of code. Otherwise you could run into race conditions with other threads.

Comment: @bestsss: atomic as in other threads cannot see "half-written values". But it does not imply that changes are visible to other threads.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný, yes long/double can be half-written unless volatile, which i mentioned. the rest (incl. references) are fine, though

Comment: @bestsss: my point was that what you call "atomicity" doesn't imply "visibility" across threads. In other words, setting a=123 in one thread doesn't make this value visible to other threads without additional synchronization. `synchronized`, `volatile` or `Atomic*` classes do guarantee visibility.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný, while I know why java memory model is designed w/ |visibility| in mind  (instead ordering), all cpus don't have infinite store buffers. For instance Atomic.`lazySet`(...) doesn't ensure visibility but in many cases it's a clear win over  `set()`.  When you want visibility, do a volatile write or a CAS (funny thing and overhead is that even failed CAS requires memory barrier), but yet it's important that something written before that write/case is not half-done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for fields that act atomically, try the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` classes. For instance, an `AtomicInteger` lets you add numbers to it atomically. If object allocation is a concern and you're sure you need it, `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater<T>` (and its ilk) can give you atomic-like access to `volatile` fields -- but you have to be careful with that, because it's easy to break your code with that approach.